# Grails DWR Plugin Service Not Injected In Controller

Tags: grails, dwr

I am new to DWR. I have tried implementing the DWR plugin in grails. I successfully integrated the plugin in grails and i am able to call the service method also.

But when i try to call a Controller method which internally calls a Service method, it throws an error saying "Not able to call the method on Null object"

I think Controller method when called from DWR is not able to get the Service method reference.

Please refer to the DWR configuration mentioned below, and let me know how to inject Service in Controller in Grails DWR plugin

Code In Bootstrap.broovy :

```
def dwrconfig = {
    service(name:'hotelService', javascript:'HotelService') {
        param (name:'class') {
            'com.tutorial.HotelService'
        }
    }

    create(creator:'new', javascript:'HotelController') {
        param (name:'class') { 'com.tutorial.HotelController' }         
    }

}
```